# data binding within property wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have been working with c# wpf for a little bit now, but ive been struggling with the concept of data binding.  I am trying to bind a label within a property but only do so when certain conditions are met.  I have a sample property that is written in winForms but I am building my app in WPF.  thanks for the help.

```
public TestSystem testSystem
{
    get { return _testSystem; }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            _testSystem = value;
            // Bind test system label to testSystem.name
            lbl_TestSystemName.DataBindings.Add("Text", testSystem, "name", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You simply need to search the web for "data binding in code behind".  This is not a problem that requires input on SO, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: is there a databindings.add method in wpf like it is in winforms

Comment: You're going about it all wrong. There's no `DataBindings` property, but yes...it's possible to create (and destroy) data bindings in code-behind. But it's almost never necessary to do so. There are lots of questions involving doing so, and I'll close this as a duplicate of one of those. But what you really want is to write a question that asks about the right way to use the WPF idioms to accomplish whatever goal led you to think that you should only add a binding in the setter of a property.